# IntelliJ community Edition and SVN

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I was using eclipse for a SVN project which is located on Assembla.
I want to create a local copy of the project. I cannot do that.
I tried using IntelliJ for the same project but unable to download my project.
I always get an empty project.
However, in the bottom view under repository, I can browse all the files in the project on Assembla.
I tried following this but no help.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-subversion-integration.html

[image: Image I can browse repository below. But no local project.]

Comment: have you added repository url in intellij?

Comment: Yes I did add the repo url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your module configuration is messed up. Probably the root directory is incorrectly configured.

Open the Project Structure window in IntelliJ (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S) and re-configure your module (a.k.a your "project") to use the proper content root. For detailed steps, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just updated to community edition 15 and it is working fine now.